# Filter out values that are in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this but with more columns. The values are beside "Department" in a list and are connected like for the first on Jenny is located in New York and is 30 years old:

| Index | Department | Team | Location | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Accounting | [Jenny, Juliet, John, Mark] | [New York, Madrid, Los Angeles, Paris] | [30,32,33,21] |
| 1 | Production | [Romeo, Michael, Lara] | [New York, Glasgow, London] | [32,26,42] |
| 2 | Management | [Marco, Patrick, Will, Lisa] | [Barcelona, Delhi, Paris, Jakarta] | [32,54,21,42] |
| 3 | Compliance | [Claire, Franco, Maria] | [Barcelona, Rom, Madrid] | [23,42,21] |

I would like to for example filter out the data from Romeo and drop the data for Romeo, New York, 32. How can I do this with Pandas?

Edit: To clarify, I would like to keep the initial Pandas Dataframe. Since I have to further use the dataframe. So the end result should look just like the dataframe above only without Romeo, New York and 32 in the second row. Would it be possible to filter out if only the Department "Production" and "Romeo" is given?

Edit2:

The output shall look like this. I would like to keep the dataframe but only delete the entries for Romeo, New York and 32. Is it possible to search for Romeo and automatically delete the other entries, since they are in the same position?:

| Index | Department | Team | Location | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Accounting | [Jenny, Juliet, John, Mark] | [New York, Madrid, Los Angeles, Paris] | [30,32,33,21] |
| 1 | Production | [Michael, Lara] | [Glasgow, London] | [26,42] |
| 2 | Management | [Marco, Patrick, Will, Lisa] | [Barcelona, Delhi, Paris, Jakarta] | [32,54,21,42] |
| 3 | Compliance | [Claire, Franco, Maria] | [Barcelona, Rom, Madrid] | [23,42,21] |

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function with lambda and apply:

```
def check (a,b,c): 
    if ('Romeo'  in a) and ('New York'  in b) and (32 in c):
        a.remove('Romeo')
        b.remove('New York')
        c.remove(32)
    
    
df['Team','Location','Age']=df.apply(lambda x: check(x['Team'], x['Location'], x['Age']),axis=1)
print(df)
'''
    Team                                 Location                             Age
0   ['Jenny', 'Juliet', 'John', 'Mark']  ['New York', 'Madrid', 'Los Angeles', 'Paris'] [30, 32, 33, 21]
1   ['Michael', 'Lara']                  ['Glasgow', 'London']                   [26, 42]
2   ['Marco', 'Patrick', 'Will', 'Lisa'] ['Barcelona', 'Delhi', 'Paris', 'Jakarta'] [32, 54, 21, 42]
3   ['Claire', 'Franco', 'Maria']        ['Barcelona', 'Rom', 'Madrid']          [23, 42, 21]

'''
```

if your column dtypes are not list first use this then apply funciton:

```
a=list(df.columns[2:4])
for i in a:
    df[i]=df[i].apply(lambda x: x.strip('][').split(', '))

import ast
df['Age']=df['Age'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```